# Javascript for each div add +1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a rank system like in this img, what I am after it doing is replacing the text with in the div and then changing to what it should be either 1, 2, 3 and etc..

What I would like to know is how can I set each divs text and then give it the value it should have.

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
function buttonclicked1() {

    allChampions1 = $(".scroll-league > #colzz");

    var selectedChampions1 = allChampions1.filter("[data-ladderdivison_id^='1']");

    allChampions1.hide();
    selectedChampions1.show();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $("div.rank").replaceWith('<div class="table-cell rank" id="rankingchangeonpage">' + i + '</div>');
    }

    document.getElementById("leagueubutton1").className = "Button SemiRound UPDATED";
    document.getElementById("leagueubutton2").className = "Button SemiRound White";
    document.getElementById("leagueubutton3").className = "Button SemiRound White";
    document.getElementById("leagueubutton4").className = "Button SemiRound White";
    document.getElementById("leagueubutton5").className = "Button SemiRound White";

    var index = 0;
    var index1 = index++;

}
```

Comment: `foreach()` that's incomplete. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: im after in javascript

Comment: Create a snippet or JSFiddle of the issue then you will get a quick and reliable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but if you have a certain set of divs you're looping through and want to increment the index each time, you could just use `.each()`. http://api.jquery.com/each/

For example, let's say those 13 rows in the graphic are a div with a `.row` class:

```
$('.row').each(function(i, elem) {
    // i is a counter that's 0-indexed, and elem represents the current
    // DOM element being looped over
    var $rank = $(elem).find('.rank');
    // set the innerHtml to 1, 2, 3, etc...
    $rank.html(i + 1);
});
```

The HTML for the above might look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="rank"></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="rank"></span>
</div>    
<div class="row">
    <span class="rank"></span>
</div>    
...
```